# Replace links with other words with PHP

Tags: php

I'm running today a dating site and in order not to lose members i would like to prevent usersfrom sending facebook links to each other.
They have a textarea where they write the conversation and this is being inserted into a MySQL DB.

Now, i would like to do when they write their facebook adress something like:

```
 https://www.facebook.com/my.nick
```

to be replaced with following text in coversation:

```
 i like you
```

Any good PHP example out there how this could be done?
/Cheerz

Comment: I have not tried yet.. I'm thinking what could be best solution for this.. Was searching on google but have not found anything yet

Comment: Hi Mensur, I see you've been contributing to the site for a while, but it might pay to read through some of [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), where you will find some advice on how to ask questions which fit well in the format of the site. Without any information on your current code, and what specifically you are stuck on, this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: Hi IMSoP good point :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_replace as

```
$str = "hello www.facebook.com. this is my fb page http://facebook.com/user-name.
Here is another one for the profile https://www.facebook.com/my-profile/?id=123.
";

$str = preg_replace('"\b((https?://|www)\S+)"', 'my new text',$str);

echo $str ;

output // hello my new text this is my fb page my new text
          Here is another one for the profile my new text
```

Or better use with

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b((https?:\/\/|www)\S+)/i', 'my new text',$str);




 /\b((https?:\/\/|www)\S+)/i

\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
1st Capturing group ((https?:\/\/|www)\S+)
    2nd Capturing group (https?:\/\/|www)
        1st Alternative: https?:\/\/
            http matches the characters http literally (case insensitive)
            s? matches the character s literally (case insensitive)
                Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            : matches the character : literally
            \/ matches the character / literally
            \/ matches the character / literally
        2nd Alternative: www
            www matches the characters www literally (case insensitive)
    \S+ match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: Adding `http` would also be a good option instead of just `https`, since if someone were to enter `http://www.facebook.com/whatever`, is a valid FB address which will redirect to `https`. Another thing to also consider is `http://www.fb.com` and all without the `www` who will all automatically redirect. Your present code may not take these factors into account; *just saying*. ;-)

Comment: `http://www.fb.com/whatever` will redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/whatever` as will `http://fb.com/whatever` so the OP might end up with people trying to "beat the system" as it were.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for pointing out that, but should `https?` will take care of both http or https. Could u please provide me a string with the example which will fail so that I can correct the above. I just added `/i` to make it case insensitive which I missed before.

Comment: You're welcome Abhik. I don't think `https?` will, maybe doing `http?` will. Yet, a question like the OP asked has too many variables at play. If I come up with anything, I will let you know. +1 nonetheless ;-)